# object as function argument

Tags: c++

I have written a simple program.

I am getting this error:

```
time.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
time.cpp:22:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘a’
time.cpp:23:4: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
time.cpp:24:4: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
time.cpp:25:4: error: ‘c’ was not declared in this scope
```

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class time
{
    int hour;
    int min;

public:
    void gettime(int h,int m)
    {
        hour=h;
        min=m;
    }

    void puttime()
    {
        cout<<hour<<endl<<min;
    }

    void sum(time x,time y)
    {
        min=x.min+y.min;
        hour=min/60;
        min=min%60;
        hour=hour+x.hour+y.hour;
    }
};

int main()
{
    time a,b,c;
    a.gettime(2,45);
    b.gettime(3,35);
    c.sum(a,b);
    a.puttime();
    b.putime();
    c.puttime();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` might bring in a function called `time()` from the standard library.

Comment: Find a new name. `Time` springs to mind.

Comment: Change `time` to say `Time` throughout and also fix the typo `b.putime();` -> `b.puttime();`.

Comment: An alternative approach to `using nampespace std` here would be `using std::cout` and `using std::endl`. That is, only bring the things from std you actuall use into scope.

Comment: Concerning the name `time`, I would suggest two things: 1) put your class `time` in a namespace. 2) Do not use `using namespace std` directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b.putime() must be b.puttime() here. Otherwise this code compiled

Answer (score 5):

Remember that there is a standard function named [`time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time).

This is the one main reason you should refrain from `using namespace std;`.